# Where does Ghostscript need to be installed if I want to use it with imagemagick in XAMPP

Tags: php, imagemagick, xampp, ghostscript

So I am using the local installed server XAMPP with imagemagick to convert pdf files into images, but I need Ghostscript too .. Installing ghostscript , does it need to be installed in the XAMPP folder too in order for imagemagick to communicate with it or can I just install it normally by clicking here `http://sourceforge.net/projects/ghostscript/?source=dlp` and install it

Because for imagemagick , I had to install it , placed the folder in the xampp directory , then add the php_imagick.dll file in the php/ext folder , then edit php.ini, which it worked..
what should be done about ghostscript though ? just download it normally and it will work wherever it's placed ?

Answer (score 0):

yes, i have the same scenario in which im using different tools beside ghostscript and Imagemagick 
with XAMPP, installing imagemagick will add it to the environment variables that you can call from anywhere, but as for the Ghostscript you should download it normally at a specific place, then call it from inside the project from that fixed path .